# ReactJS + Redux: How to use Material-UI's RaisedButton as <input/>?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I want to use Material-UI's RaisedButton ( http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button ) as `<input/>` so I tried the following:

```
      <RaisedButton
        containerElement={<input type="file" onChange={this._handleImageChange}/>}
        label="Upload Image"
        labelColor='#88898C'
        labelStyle={{textTransform:'intial'}}
        backgroundColor='#1C1C1F'
      />
```

but I get an error `Invariant Violation: input is a void element tag and must not have "children" or use "props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML". Check the render method`.

Is there a way to do so? I would like the RaisedButton to act like that of `<input type="file" onChange={this._handleImageChange}/>`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you think the `containerElement` is supposed to do?  I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: OK, it seems `containerElement` is the element that will contain the button.  What are you attempting by putting the `input` there?  Are you trying to do a file upload with a `RaisedButton`?

Comment: @DavinTryon Yup that's exactly what I want to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of "containerElement" will be the element that *contains* your button (in other words, the button's parent or wrapper). An HTML input is not allowed to contain any other elements, hence the error.

Put your input as the button's child:

```
<RaisedButton label="Upload Image"
              labelColor='#88898C'
              labelStyle={{textTransform:'intial'}}
              backgroundColor='#1C1C1F'>
  <input type="file" onChange={this._handleImageChange}/>
</RaisedButton>
```